# Naming convention for query parameters when searching by a list of associated entity

Tags: rest

What is the naming convention in REST API for query parameters when searching by properties of multiple associated entities?

I am writing a service which stores courses and students. There is many-to-many relation between courses and students.
I must add an API which is going to allow searching courses by properties of students (e.g. first names, last names or ids) who are enrolled in these courses.
This API must support searching by multiple values at once. Multiple values are separated by common, for example: 123,234,345.

I am struggling with names of such parameters.
Should I use:

1. Singular form "student first name": GET /api/v1/courses?student-first-name=James,Paul,Henry
2. Plural form "student first names": GET /api/v1/courses?student-first-names=James,Paul,Henry
3. Plural possessive form "students' first names": GET /api/v1/courses?students-first-names=James,Paul,Henry

Comment: There are various standards, you could look into OData(https://www.odata.org/) and the Microsoft REST api spec (https://github.com/Microsoft/api-guidelines).

Comment: Any spelling convention you want to use is _fine_.  The machine's don't care (in much the same way that compilers/interpreters don't care about the spelling of variable names), so you can choose any spelling that is convenient for the humans that are most important to you.